# how can I solve this android studio problem?

Tags: android

I'm new to Android Studio and I have a RelativeLayout in which I have a simple TextView. But unfortunately, I can not see my TextView in the design mode of my XML file. Here are my XML code and design of that XML file. does anybody know how should I solve this problem?
Thank you so much :)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/welcome_message" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you share with us some captures of your problem?

Comment: Cross check your theme as well, it should be generally AppTheme

Comment: your link for image is incorrect, please re upload your picture

Comment: Just check with some static text like text="welcome" & if possible any background color for textview. If still it is not visible "Invalidate cache and restart" the android studio.

Comment: clear cache and restart your android studio

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="hello"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

You can try this easy example that for me works.
If it doesn't work try to rebuild the android studio project.

Comment: Color of the phone screen in design mode is not white, it's grey!!!!

Comment: try to add color attribute to textview like #36f636

Comment: I don't know why when I start a new project with Empty activity, its layout is constraintLayout, not RelativeLayout

Comment: because constraint layout is the layout that should replace the relative layout and for that reason is the default layout. Because is more performant than the previous.